# Bobby should be good for a few drinks

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Bobby should be good for a few drinks.

What does this sentence mean?

Comment: You could have got an answer to your question by simply looking on the Internet. [link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-good-for-sth)

Answer (score 4):

From [Collins...](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/be-good-for)

> **be good for**
> If someone is good for something, you can rely on them to provide that thing.
> *Joe was always good for a colorful quote*.
> *He was stupid, useless, and good for nothing but his money.*

In the cited context, the speaker is saying he and his friend(s) can rely on Bobby to pay for a drinking session.